# Moving a distance at a position vector

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a problem set in which the problem states from vector $a = 4i+3j+8k$ move lets say $2$ metres in the direction of the vector $r = 1i + 2j +5k$. What is your final position?

I know how to add vetors and however I am not sure how to deal with it when they you must move a certain number of meters in the direction of another vector.

Must I multiply the vector by the $2$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are always dealing in meters, then you need to normalize the vector $\mathbf{r}$ and multiply it by $2$. Then normalized vector is found by 
$$\mathbf{n}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{||\mathbf{r}||}$$
Where $||\mathbf{r}||=\sqrt{1^2+2^2+5^2}$.
Normalizing the vector gives you the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{r}$ . Then you add $\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{r}$.